# str_ireplace for file_put_content not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I tried replacing ##email## with customer email. this works for the body of the email, but doesn't work for attachments.

```
$attachfile = file_get_contents("attachment/test.txt");
$attachfile = str_ireplace("##email##", $customeremail, $attachfile);
$tempattach = tempnam("/tmp", 'prefix');
file_put_contents($tempattach.".txt", $attachfile);
$mail->addAttachment($tempattach.".txt", "Hello.txt"]), "base64");
unlink($tempattach.".txt");
```

Comment: **Did you think that code was compiling?** Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Please share more details. What's the expectation for this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachments are not actually read until you send. So if you add an attachment file and delete it before sending (which is what you're doing), it will not be sent.

From what you're doing though, it looks like you might be better off skipping the external files and doing that substitution and attachment all in memory using [`addStringAttachment`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment) like this:

```php
$attachfile = file_get_contents("attachment/test.txt");
$attachfile = str_ireplace("##email##", $customeremail, $attachfile);
$mail->addStringAttachment($attachfile, "Hello.txt");
```